# Why do these two numpy.divide operations give such different results?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, division, array-broadcasting

I would like to correct the values in hyperspectral readings from a cameara using the formula described over [here](https://eufat.github.io/2019/02/19/hyperspectral-image-preprocessing-with-python.html);

> the captured data is subtracted by dark reference and divided with
> white reference subtracted dark reference.

In the original example, the task is rather simple, white and dark reference has the same shape as the main data so the formula is executed as:

```
corrected_nparr = np.divide(np.subtract(data_nparr, dark_nparr),
np.subtract(white_nparr, dark_nparr))
```

However the main data is much larger in my experience. Shapes in my case are as following;

```
$ white_nparr.shape, dark_nparr.shape, data_nparr.shape
((100, 640, 224), (100, 640, 224), (4300, 640, 224))
```

that's why I `repeat` the reference arrays.

```
   white_nparr_rep = white_nparr.repeat(43, axis=0)
   dark_nparr_rep = dark_nparr.repeat(43, axis=0)
return np.divide(np.subtract(data_nparr, dark_nparr_rep), np.subtract(white_nparr_rep, dark_nparr_rep))
```

And it works **almost perfect**ly, as can be seen in the **image at the left**. But this approach requires **enormous** amount of **memory**, so I decided to traverse the large array and replace the original values with corrected ones on-the-go instead:

```
ref_scale = dark_nparr.shape[0]
data_scale = data_nparr.shape[0]

for i in range(int(data_scale / ref_scale)):
    data_nparr[i*ref_scale:(i+1)*ref_scale] = 
        np.divide
        ( 
        np.subtract(data_nparr[i*ref_scale:(i+1)*ref_scale], dark_nparr),
        np.subtract(white_nparr, dark_nparr)
        )
```

But that traversal approach gives me the **ugliest of results, as can be seen in the right**. I'd appreciate any idea that would help me fix this.

Note: I apply 20-times co-adding (mean of 20 readings) to obtain the images below.

EDIT: `dtype` of each array is as following:

```
$ white_nparr.dtype, dark_nparr.dtype, data_nparr.dtype
(dtype('float32'), dtype('float32'), dtype('float32'))
```

[image: left image]  [image: right image]

Comment: Please provide the `dtype` of each array like you did with `shape`.

Comment: @JérômeRichard thanks for the suggestion. Updated.

Comment: Note that you can store the result of `np.subtract` and `np.divide` in preallocated temporary buffer using the `out` parameter so to avoid the creation/filling of many temporary array. This takes less memory and should be faster.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I will try this one as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your two methods don't agree because in the first method you used

```
   white_nparr_rep = white_nparr.repeat(43, axis=0)
```

but the second method corresponds to using

```
   white_nparr_rep = np.tile(white_nparr, (43, 1, 1))
```

If the first method is correct, you'll have to adjust the second method to act accordingly.  Perhaps

```
for i in range(int(data_scale / ref_scale)):
    data_nparr[i*ref_scale:(i+1)*ref_scale] = 
        np.divide
        ( 
        np.subtract(data_nparr[i*ref_scale:(i+1)*ref_scale], dark_nparr[i]),
        np.subtract(white_nparr[i], dark_nparr[i])
        )
```

---

A simple example with 2-d arrays that shows the difference between `repeat` and `tile`:

```
In [146]: z
Out[146]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]])

In [147]: np.repeat(z, 3, axis=0)
Out[147]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]])

In [148]: np.tile(z, (3, 1))
Out[148]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

---

Off topic postscript:  I don't know why the author of the page that you linked to writes NumPy expressions as (for example):

```
corrected_nparr = np.divide(
    np.subtract(data_nparr, dark_nparr),
    np.subtract(white_nparr, dark_nparr))
```

NumPy allows you to write that as

```
corrected_nparr = (data_nparr - dark_nparr) / (white_nparr - dark_nparr)
```

whick looks much nicer to me.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will try that right away.